# Spring-Security.. 5.1.5 RELEASE to Spring -Security.. 5.4.6 breaks security configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-rest

**Summary**
Updated Spring boot project from 2.1.5 RELEASE to 2.4.5 Version. It automictically updated all Spring Security dependencies from version Spring-Security.. 5.1.5 RELEASE to Spring -Security.. 5.4.6 breaks security configuration

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure anyRequest after itself
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure anyRequest after itself
at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76) ~[spring-core-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.anyRequest(AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.java:72) ~[spring-security-config-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
at com.verizon.wfm.nt.config.SecurityConfig.configure(SecurityConfig.java:14) ~[default/:?]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:217) ~[spring-security-config-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]

**security configuration**
Working code

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
@override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
super.configure(httpSecurity);
httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
httpSecurity.csrf().disable();
httpSecurity.headers().frameOptions().disable();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling `super.configure(httpSecurity)` it does the following:

```java
http.authorizeRequests((requests) -> requests.anyRequest().authenticated());
http.formLogin();
http.httpBasic();
```

After that, you are configuring the requests using the `anyRequest` again. It is not allowed in recent versions of Spring Security.

What I suggest you do is not calling the `super.configure(httpSecurity)` and instead disabling the defaults and configuring them, like so:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.formLogin().disable();
        httpSecurity.httpBasic().disable();
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests((requests) ->
            requests.anyRequest().permitAll()
        );
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable();
        httpSecurity.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }
}
```

Comment: It works Marcus like below!!  Thanks Marcus.  httpSecurity.formLogin().disable();
  httpSecurity.httpBasic().disable();
  // httpSecurity.authorizeRequests((requests) ->
  // requests.anyRequest().permitAll());
  httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
  httpSecurity.csrf().disable();
  httpSecurity.headers().frameOptions().disable();

Comment: Yes Marcus. Thanks a lot!